# How to include sub class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, include

can somebody please help me with this dot .net mvc question:

I have these classes:

```
public class ImportItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ImportItemListTemplate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ImportItem> ImportItemList { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ImportItemListTemplate> ImportItemListTemplates { get; set; }
}
```

In controller I need to set this:

```
Context context = new Context();
int id = ...;
ImportItemListTemplate tmp = context.ImportItemListTemplates.Find(id);
```

But this doesnt include ImportItemList from the ImportItemListTemplate class. I think i need to include the property ImportItemList, but I dont know how.

I tried somethink like:

```
ImportItemListTemplate tmp = context.ImportItemListTemplates.Include(i => i.ImportItemList).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

But it doesnt work. Error:

> *"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because its not
>   delegate type"*

Thank you much for you help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] and [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: You're missing a using statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like below,

```
ImportItemListTemplate tmp = context.ImportItemListTemplates.Include("ImportItemList").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: One additional question: imagine I have another property (of my class - DbTbl) in the class ImportItem. I want to include it too. I tried somethink like this:

ImportItemListTemplate tmp = context.ImportItemListTemplates.Include("ImportItemList").Include("DbTbl").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

But id doesnt work. I gues, it will be ok if the property would be in the same level (property of ImportItemListTemplates class), not under this level.

I will be very thankful for this reply too.

Comment: Dear Petr, you have to add a navigation property in ImportItemListTemplate class. It looks like `public virtual List<DbTbl> DbTbls { get; set; }` 
For more additional information you can try this  [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImportItemListTemplate tmp = context.ImportItemListTemplates
                                    .Include(i => i.ImportItemList)
                                    .Where(x => x.Id)
                                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.
The Uzmanim.Net answer was what I was looking for - just string property name. There is the same error in your sollution like in my (if I understood well).

Answer (score 0):

The [`DbSet.Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) accepts a string, so it won't be happy with a lambda.

I guess what you need is the [`IQueryable<T>.Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679205%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) extension method which is in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, especially the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that accepts an expression. With it you can use syntax like

```
query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection)
```

to load a collection property from the database.
Add the namespace if it's not added to the `using` list and try the code again.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Thats right - I can't use lambda.
Uzmanim.Net sollution is clear and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I added this namespace and its ok now .-) Thanks.